# MongoDB move data into documents between collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I need to move data between collections as they were previously designed using relational model in mind and we're having some lookup performance issues. Note that the data shown is only an example and i need to do this for a large set of data.
The data structure is as follows:

```
// Collection person
{
   _id: <object_id>
   ...other data
}
// Collection employments
{
    _id: <object_id>
    person_id: <person_id>,
    ... other data,
}
```

Now i need to move all data from `employments` collection to `person` collection based on `person_id` and `employment_id`. And i won't be deleting `employments` collection as I also need to move some metadata from `person` collection to `employment` collection due to some usecases.

**Edit:**

A `person` can have multiple `employments`. So I'll need to replace all the `ids` inside `person` by actual `employments` data. Also employment has `person_id` which needs to be replaced(can create a new property say `person` instead of replacing `person_id`) by some metadata of `person`(e.g. name, email..).

[$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) seems promising. Will need to try it out. Seems confusing to me.

**An example of result wanted:**

The documents in two collections look like below:

**Person Collection**

```
{
  "_id": "619cf3045ce7329d6a8c059c",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "email": "johndoe@mail.com",
  "contact": 1234567890
}
```

**Employment Collection**

```
// Two documents related to person above
  // Document one
  {
    "_id": "619cf89913380c621ea8d4ec",
    "person_id": "619cf3045ce7329d6a8c059c",
    "employment_type": "Owner",
    "yearly_income": 10000000
  }
  // Document two
  {
    "_id": "619cf912374db5aec2ceb6de",
    "person_id": "619cf3045ce7329d6a8c059c",
    "employment_type": "Salary",
    "yearly_income": 12340000
  }
```

**Expected result for person collection to be updated as**

```
{
  "_id": "619cf3045ce7329d6a8c059c",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "email": "johndoe@mail.com",
  "contact": 1234567890,
  "employments": [
    {
    "_id": "619cf89913380c621ea8d4ec",
    "person_id": "619cf3045ce7329d6a8c059c",
    "employment_type": "Owner",
    "yearly_income": 10000000
    },
    {
      "_id": "619cf912374db5aec2ceb6de",
      "person_id": "619cf3045ce7329d6a8c059c",
      "employment_type": "Salary",
      "yearly_income": 12340000
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected result for employment collection to be updated as**

**Note: `employment_type` and `yearly_income` are not needed when the collection is updated(can be removed)**

```
  // Document one
  {
    "_id": "619cf89913380c621ea8d4ec",
    "person_id": "619cf3045ce7329d6a8c059c",
    "person": {
      "_id": "619cf3045ce7329d6a8c059c",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "email": "johndoe@mail.com",
      "contact": 1234567890
    }
  }
  // Document two
  {
    "_id": "619cf912374db5aec2ceb6de",
    "person_id": "619cf3045ce7329d6a8c059c",
    "person": {
      "_id": "619cf3045ce7329d6a8c059c",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "email": "johndoe@mail.com",
      "contact": 1234567890
    }
  }
```

Any solution somewhat close to this is very much acceptable.

Comment: Have a look at [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) Please provide some more details. `employments` is an array, but `person_id` is a scalar value, so you would need some transformation, e.g. `$group` or `$unwind`

Comment: I have added an edit @wernfried-domscheit. Please check it out.

Comment: Please provide more details for the documents. We don't need to see all of then, just 2-3 as reference. An please provide desired result.

Comment: The documents are nearly identical to the edit showcase. I've also included the desired result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
db.person.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: "employment",
         localField: "_id",
         foreignField: "person_id",
         as: "employments"
      }
   },
   { $merge: { into: "person" } }
])
```

If you like to modify collection `employment` then use it like this:

```
db.person.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: "employment",
         localField: "_id",
         foreignField: "person_id",
         pipeline: [{ $unset: ["employment_type", "yearly_income"] }],
         as: "employments"
      }
   },
   { $merge: { into: "person" } }
])
```